# HTML 5 dynamically loaded videos causing black screen on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, video

I'm loading in videos dynamically by changing the `video` tag's `src` in code. When I try my code on an ipad (no idea if it works in the simulator or not), the first video plays fine but the next one just gives me a black screen. I have tried playing the second video first (to check for encoding issues) and it plays fine.

Here is my javascript function that loads/plays the video:

```
function loadVideo(video_path){  
    var vid = document.getElementById('v');

    vid.src = video_path;
    vid.load();

    // play the video once it has loaded
    vid.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(e){
        vid.style.display = "block";
        vid.play();
    }, false);

    // hide the video container once the video has finished playing
    vid.addEventListener('ended', function(e){
        vid.style.display = "none";
    }, false);
}
```

Called from my code like:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    switch(video){
        case 0:
            loadVideo('path/to/myvideo.mp4');
            break;
        case 1:
            loadVideo('path/to/myvideo2.mp4');
            break;
        case 2:
            loadVideo('path/to/myvideo3.mp4');
            break;
        // etc
    }

    video++;
});
```

And my html inside the `body` tag:

```
<video id="v" type="video/h264" width="960" height="500"></video>
```

I have tried removing the `video` tag after each play and inserting it in again but that had no effect. Ideas welcome! :)

Comment: What does the video variable in your second block of code represent? I don't see it defined anywhere in your first block of code. It's tough to say what's going on without knowing the full extent of what your code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a solution for your exact question, but the concepts are there and you should be able to adjust it to your own code (the full extent of which I'm not privy to, of course). The following code is something I put together to have the VIDEO element load in and play the next video source in a queue automatically after the current video source is done.

The reason I use timeupdate to check for the video being "near" the end instead of just looking for the ended event is because the ended event is notoriously unreliable on older devices (such as the original iPad). You can use the ended event if you so wish, of course.

```
(function ($) {
    var srcs = [
        "video1.mp4",
        "video2.mp4",
        "video3.mp4",
        "video4.mp4"
    ],
    index = 0,
    $video = $("#vid").attr("src", srcs[index]).bind("timeupdate", timeUpdateHandler),
    video = $video.get(0);

    function timeUpdateHandler(e) {
        if (video.currentTime >= (video.duration - 0.1)) {
            nextVideo();
        }
    }

    function nextVideo() {
        index++;
        if (index === srcs.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        $video.attr("src", srcs[index]);
        video.play();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Let me know if this helps you or if you have any questions.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction - the problem I was having was related to binding new event handlers without unbinding the 'old' ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<video onended="javascript:on_video_ended();"></video>
<script>
function on_video_ended(){
    //javascript code goes here.
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was doing all of this in code so this solution wouldn't have worked.